# Is it possible to integrate 3rd Party Ads like Adsense/Adbmob with Video.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am using `video.js` library for the video player. It does support showing custom Ads provided by you but could not find the way to integrate 3rd party services like Adsense. Can anyone guide me in this regard? The `contrib-ads` plugin seems for custom Ads file only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available for videojs support of adsense - see here:

- https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima

It is actively being updated (at the time of writing) and some of the leading contributors are from Google.